# How to pass props to child class in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have tried to pass properties to child class component from parent class. But I am getting an error in parent class while passing properties.

**My code snippet:**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import CartesianChart  from './chart/cartesian';
import Chart2 from './chart/chart2';

export interface IData {
  x: string;
  y: number;
  r: string;
}

export let data1: IData[] = [
  { x: 'Argentina', y: 505370, r: '100' },
  { x: 'Belgium', y: 551500, r: '118.7' },
  { x: 'Cuba', y: 312685, r: '124.6' },
  { x: 'Dominican Republic', y: 350000, r: '137.5' },
  { x: 'Egypt', y: 301000, r: '150.8' },
  { x: 'Kazakhstan', y: 300000, r: '155.5' },
  { x: 'Somalia', y: 357022, r: '160.6' }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Chart2 data={data1}/>
        <CartesianChart data={data1}/>
      </div >
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**I am getting error message like this**
[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you instantiate the `App` component? Pass the data as props there, then you can pass this data prop to child components.

Comment: In index.tsx, I have instantiate the `App` component. I have passed data as props in App component. Still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the parent class props declaration.

it should be like this,

```
interface IProps {
  data: IData[]
}
class CartesianChart extends React.Component<IProps> {

}
```